# Modify Linq code, add AND statement to join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

My LinQ code:

```
var query = ctx.PERSON.Where(p => p.EMAIL == login && p.PASSWD == pass && p.STATUS == 1)
                    .Join(ctx.INSTITUTION, p => p.FK_INSTITUTION, inst => inst.ID,(person, institution) => new {person, institution})
                    .Join(ctx.PERSON_INSTITUTION, p => p.person.ID, perProj => perProj.FK_PERSON, (p, perProj) => new {p, perProj})
                    //.Join(ctx.PROJECT, p => p.perProj.FK_INSTITUTION, proj => proj.ID, (p, proj) => new {p, proj})
                    .Join(ctx.PRIVILEGE_ROLE, p => p.perProj.FK_ROLE, privRol => privRol.FK_ROLE,(p, privRol) => new {p, privRol})
                    .Join(ctx.PRIVILEGE, p => p.privRol.FK_PRIVILEGE, priv => priv.ID, (p, priv) => new {p, priv})
                    .Where(p => p.priv.NAME == "resource/mul/upload")
                    .Select(
                        p =>
                            new UserModel
                            {
                                Login = p.p.p.p.person.EMAIL,
                                FirstName = p.p.p.p.person.NAME,
                                LastName = p.p.p.p.person.SURNAME,
                                UserId = p.p.p.p.person.ID,
                                InstitutionId = p.p.p.p.institution.ID,
                                InstitutionName = p.p.p.p.institution.NAME,
                                OrganizationUnitId = (decimal)p.p.p.p.institution.FK_SWD_ORGANIZATION_UNIT
                            });
```

It generates sql like this:

```
SELECT
1 AS `C1`, 
`Extent1`.`EMAIL`, 
`Extent1`.`NAME`, 
`Extent1`.`SURNAME`, 
`Extent1`.`ID`, 
`Extent2`.`ID` AS `ID1`, 
`Extent2`.`NAME` AS `NAME1`, 
`Extent2`.`FK_SWD_ORGANIZATION_UNIT`
FROM `PERSON` AS `Extent1` 
INNER JOIN `INSTITUTION` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`FK_INSTITUTION` = `Extent2`.`ID` 
INNER JOIN `PERSON_INSTITUTION` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent1`.`ID` = `Extent3`.`FK_PERSON` 
INNER JOIN `PRIVILEGE_ROLE` AS `Extent4` ON `Extent3`.`FK_ROLE` = `Extent4`.`FK_ROLE` 
INNER JOIN `PRIVILEGE` AS `Extent5` ON `Extent4`.`FK_PRIVILEGE` = `Extent5`.`ID`
WHERE (1 = (`Extent1`.`STATUS`)) AND (((`Extent1`.`EMAIL` = @p__linq__0) AND (`Extent1`.`PASSWD` = @p__linq__1)) AND (@gp1 = `Extent5`.`NAME`))
```

I'm not sure how to modify my linq query to get sql ouput like this:

```
SELECT
1 AS `C1`, 
`Extent1`.`EMAIL`, 
`Extent1`.`NAME`, 
`Extent1`.`SURNAME`, 
`Extent1`.`ID`, 
`Extent2`.`ID` AS `ID1`, 
`Extent2`.`NAME` AS `NAME1`, 
`Extent2`.`FK_SWD_ORGANIZATION_UNIT`
FROM `PERSON` AS `Extent1` 
INNER JOIN `INSTITUTION` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`FK_INSTITUTION` = `Extent2`.`ID` 
INNER JOIN `PERSON_INSTITUTION` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent1`.`ID` = `Extent3`.`FK_PERSON` AND `Extent3`.`STATUS`=1
INNER JOIN `PRIVILEGE_ROLE` AS `Extent4` ON `Extent3`.`FK_ROLE` = `Extent4`.`FK_ROLE` 
INNER JOIN `PRIVILEGE` AS `Extent5` ON `Extent4`.`FK_PRIVILEGE` = `Extent5`.`ID`
WHERE (1 = (`Extent1`.`STATUS`)) AND (((`Extent1`.`EMAIL` = @p__linq__0) AND (`Extent1`.`PASSWD` = @p__linq__1)) AND (@gp1 = `Extent5`.`NAME`))
```

So I need to add AND `Extent3`.`STATUS`=1 to my join. Any suggestion how to modify above linq query to get neede result?

Comment: Just add that condition to where clause, for inner joins it's the same.

Comment: You can just add it to the where.  Also why don't you use navigation properties instead of joins https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: Hmm, this is not my code and I'm rather newbie int it.... how to add it to where? Sorry for stupid question

Comment: `p.p.p.p.person` for goodness sake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the Where to the LINQ where

```
.Where(p => p.priv.NAME == "resource/mul/upload")
```

becomes

```
.Where(p => p.priv.NAME == "resource/mul/upload" && p.perProj.Status ==1)
```

It is hard to guess p.perProj but intellisense should help you out.

Comment: It seems to be 'p.p.p.perProj.STATUS==1' ?

Comment: Give it a go chap, i can't read linq all that well without intellisense.